# html javascript reverts to default after javascript has run

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript and we have been given the task of changing image / colour of paragraph from the click of the button. My code works but I had to add an alert() to stop it to show this as it reverts to default image/colour as soon as it runs.

```js
function changeImage() {
    var myTag=document.getElementById("imageColour");
    myTag.src = "images/white.jpg";
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.color = "red";
    // Had to add this to see change
    alert("Has reached changeImage()");
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <title>Exercise 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <h3>Exercise 3</h3>
 <img src="images/black.jpg" id="imageColour"/>
 <form>
     <button type="submit" id="mySubmitButton">Change Colour</button>
 </form>
 <p id="demo">Click the button to change the colour of this paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<!--javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mySubmitButton").addEventListener("click", changeImage);
</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting a form. That causes the page to be reloaded and reset.

Use `type="button"` (and you might as well remove the form entirely while you are at it) or call `preventDefault` on the event object (the first argument to `changeImage`).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. When you say use type="button" do you mean instead of type="submit". Also, if I add preventDefault to my function, can I still use a form?

Comment: Yes. Yes, but there is no point since you don't have any other fields and you aren't submitting the (non-existent) data anywhere.